# React Router gives me 404 error on bluehost

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

Hello i have a project that is using Router

---

Whenever i click on Blogs it gives me 404 Error

---

This is my app.js code

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";

import Blogs from "../src/Components/Blogs";

function App() {
  return (
    
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          
          <Route exact path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/Blogs"}`} component={Blogs} />

        </Switch>
      </Router>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

Comment: 404 error means that the page not found, so the problem almost in path, so what is the value of ${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/Blogs"}?

Comment: @asmaa the value of ${process.env.PUBLIC_URL} is the home page and also I've changed it to "./Blogs" but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with the .htaccess file i had to put this inside it

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```